# Possibly synonymous tags: [wcc], [world-champions], [championship]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [wcc](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wcc), [world-champions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-champions), and [championship](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/championship) have such major overlap in scope that I think we should merge them down to one or two tags.

Obviously [championship](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/championship)  [can be merged into](https://chess.stackexchange.com/tags/world-champions/synonyms) [world-champions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-champions), but my question to the community is: should we merge [wcc](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wcc) as well, or simply leave that one as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference would be to replace all of [wcc](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wcc), [world-champions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-champions) and [championship](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/championship) with a single tag named [world-championship](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-championship). I think that a tag so named should be able to comfortably subsume the slightly different purviews intended by those other tags.